# XmlDocument failed to load XHTML string because of error "Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'"

Tags: c#, xml

I use the following code to translate the HTTP response stream into a XmlDocument.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
String responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseString);
Int32 htmlTagIndex = responseString.IndexOf("<html",
   StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
XmlDocument responseXhtml = new XmlDocument();
responseString = responseString.Substring(htmlTagIndex); // MARK 1
responseString = responseString.Replace("&nbsp", " "); // MARK 2
responseXhtml.LoadXml(responseString);
return responseXhtml;
```

The **MARK 1** line is to skip the DOC Type definition line.

The **MARK 2** line is to avoid the error **Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'**.

Is there any better way to do this? There're too much string operation in the above code.

Thanks!

Comment: HTML Agility Pack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: Thanks, but the HTML Agility Pack seems to be an over-kill. Any simple code?

Comment: (X)HTML is usually not XML. `&nbsp;` is an entity defined in HTML. Do you really need to load this as XML?

Comment: Hmmm, good point, maybe I don't need to convert it to XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would directly use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse the html. Even if you have to convert html to xml, you can use it.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com"));
    doc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    doc.Save(writer);

    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(writer.ToString()));
}
```